# histogram construction in bag of words algorithm

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I am implementing bag of words algorithm for image classification in matlab. I have done the k means clustering of the features and divided in 250 clusters. I am unable to understand how to draw the histogram.

Answer (score 0):

Draw, as in plot?  You can use the `bar` function, which will make you a bar graph.

Also there is [support for bag of features](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/image-category-classification-using-bag-of-features.html) in the Computer Vision System Toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have trained your codebook with kmeans ( in your case k=250). The training should be done with all available features from your dataset. In order to estimate the bag-of-words histogram for an image, you have to assign a cluster for each image. Therefore assign for each feature a cluster, that has the minimal distance to the feature (e.g. use L2 distance). Then histgram bin n counts the number of features that have the minimal distance to cluster n. Histogram dimension is in your case 250 as well.